# Is there a way to publish Selenium failed tests screenshots in Jenkins?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, msbuild, mstest

I am running selenium tests in Jenkins and want to publish report including screenshots of failed tests.

Is there a way to publish Selenium failed tests screenshots in Jenkins?

Comment: if you use extent report. you can attach screen shot and using publish html plugin to publish the html report on jenkins.

Comment: what do you mean by publish screenshot ? there could be a way based on which automation framework you are using

Comment: While the tests are runnning it is creating the screenshots and putting into the folder but like with mstest report publish plugin it is only publishing the test cases not the screenshots because it needs to be configured some where i.e, the screenshot folder path like we have in ccnet.